# How a value will be rounded in Linux environment?

Tags: java

I have a small program collect data from Oracle Database and show on GUI in Linux.
At database: value = 4.25
But after I get value and show data on GUI with type double. I have value = 4.2

In Linux machine, How a value will be rounded? 
(value greater than 0.005 will be rounded to 0.01 or value greater and equal 0.005 will be rounded to  0.01)

Ex:

```
#1/ 4.25 will be rounded to 4.2
#2/ 4.25 will be rounded to 4.3
```

Which one is true: #1 or #2?

Please help me verify this problem.

Comment: Convert your data to string.....

Comment: This is impossible to answer. It doesn't depend on whether your GUI runs on Linux. Show us the code that formats the number in the GUI.

Comment: @Jesper While I agree that the question lacks information, sometimes rounding routines do behave differently depending on the OS.

Comment: @NullUserException This question is about Java, which is supposed to shield you from platform-dependent behaviour like that.

Comment: @Jesper: yes, Java *mostly* shields you from platform-dependence. The only one it does *not* shield you from is that calculations can be *more precise* than expected (for example 80bit instead of 64bit), which can lead to slightly different results after rounding. But even that can be turned of using `strictfp`. But I guess that's not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding will be according to #2 - 4.25 will be rounded to 4.3. Still note that what you see as 4.25 could easily be 4.249999999999 in which case rounding to 1 decimal digit will result to 4.2.

Comment: That is the case if you have double u = 4.25. How about if the 4.25 is the result of some calculations? My point was that what he sees as 4.25 might easily be something VERY close to 4.25, but below that value.